# How to find duplicates by name filtered by geo coordinate

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I need to find duplicate entries (accommodations) by name which will be done like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_folded AS
SELECT name
     , array_agg(id) AS ids
FROM   accommodations
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Which is fine to get all the ids of accommodations with same name, unfortunately they need further filtering. I just need to get accommodation of same name within a location.
Every accommodation has an address (addresses table has foreign key, accommodation_id and lonlat column for the geo coordinate).
In order to find the closest locations I would go for s.th. like this

```
ORDER BY ST_Distance(addresses.lonlat, addresses.lonlat)
```

So how can I extend the query above to apply this location filtering?
Help is very much appreciated.

```
   Column    |          Type          |                          Modifiers                          
-------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                | not null default nextval('accommodations_id_seq'::regclass)
 name        | character varying(255) | 
 category    | character varying(255) |



                                        Table "public.addresses"
      Column      |            Type             |                       Modifiers                        
------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 id               | integer                     | not null default nextval('addresses_id_seq'::regclass)
 formatted        | character varying(255)      | 
 city             | character varying(255)      | 
 state            | character varying(255)      | 
 country_code     | character varying(255)      | 
 postal           | character varying(255)      | 
 lonlat           | geography(Point,4326)       | 
 accommodation_id | integer                     |
```

Comment: Can you post table structure for accommodations and addresses?

Comment: @Rahul Please find the update db scheme

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the duplicate `accommodation_id` from `addresses` table grouping by `lonlat` column like

```
select accommodation_id
from addresses
group by lonlat
having count(*) > 1
```

Then join this result with `accommodation` table to get the `names` column like below

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_folded AS
select ac.id,
ac.names
from accommodation ac 
join (
select accommodation_id
from addresses
group by lonlat
having count(*) > 1
) tab on ac.id = tab.accommodation_id
```

Comment: but how is your approach ensuring that filter duplicates only at the same location?

Comment: Then it should be other way. BTW, your address table has city/state. With location, do you mean within same city or within same state?

Comment: Should be city but that does not matter in this case because I know that I have duplicates of accommodations with the same name but their address.city is resolved to different city names, so the only thing to rely on is the lonlat coordindate

Comment: grouping by lonlat is not valid since the coordinate might differ slightly

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by within a location, seeing as you say grouping by lonlat is no good.

Comment: @dc10, can you show sample data from both tables. It's bit confusing what you mean by within location?

Comment: @JohnBarça lonlat is a geometry point consisting of longitude/latitude.

Comment: @Rahul the addresses table has a lonlat field which is geo point. So the filtering should take into consideration that I want accomodations having the same name but only for a location e.g. NewYork. So having a two hotels named Plaza hotel in Chicago should group them but not a Plaza Hotel in New York. Please see my answer and how I approached.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I solved it. I just filter coordinates within a radius

```
SELECT
  lower(name)                  AS base_name,
  array_agg(accommodations.id) AS ids

FROM accommodations
  INNER JOIN addresses ON accommodations.id = addresses.accommodation_id

GROUP BY 1, round(ST_X(lonlat::geometry)::numeric,2), round(ST_Y(lonlat::geometry)::numeric,2)
```

Comment: You would probably be better using ST_Dwithin than rounding geometry coordinates.